# is there a better way to call api after first one done?

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I'm trying to find the best way to handle APIs, when some component have to call multiples but needs to wait step by step.

What I do, is working perfectly fine. But I don't know if this is a right way to do.
Could any one point out or make an easy example for the better solution?

Thank you.

```
someService1().subscribe(res => {
// result
},(error =>{
// handle it
},(()=> {
 someService2().subscribe(res2=>{
///
})
}));
```

Comment: for step by step execution use .concat()

Comment: [Decision tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) should explain, which operator you need

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple observables to get a single observable, the exact operator you need would be highly scenario specific.

refer for all available combination methods, https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/

You could probably use merge to get the desired result
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html